# owl carousel тормозит в safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, owl-carousel

На главной странице https://nikaestate.ru/ есть карусель изображений. При свайпах на ios в safari происходит подтормаживание. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сталкивался кто-нибудь с подобным?

Comment: Уточните версию ios/safari. На старых смартфонах в любом случае будет тормозить.

Comment: Проверял на iphone 6 и Iphone 8 12.4.1 ios